# Additional validation after successful login

Tags: 7, users

I want to implement some additional validation steps right after a user has logged in to a Drupal site.

So far, I have implemented the additional validation inside `hook_user_login`. If the validation fails, I am forcing the logout by calling `user_logout`.

---

**EDIT**: Part of the users are authenticated through an external SSO, so altering the login form to add an additional validation does not seem to be a good solution.

---

Is this the most standard way to do it, or is there a better way?

Comment: What are you validating ? Some inputs from the register form or login ?

Comment: I am validating the username against an ad-hoc service implemented somewhere else. It just gives a "Go - NoGo" response. I need to abort the login in case the response is "NoGo".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Marcin and skh for your answers. Unfortunately, it seems my case is quite specific. I will post below my solution in case someone else has a similar situation:

**NOTE**: This solution assumes the site is receiving logins not coming from the standard login form. If all the logins are coming through the standard login form, it is much better to add a `#validate`in [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7), as mentioned above.

If logins to the site come from different places (such as SSO), my solution has been to implement `hook_user_login`:

```
function MYMODULE_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  $additional_validation_result = MYMODULE_additional_validation($account);
  if ($additional_validation_result === TRUE) {
    // Additional validation passed. Just return
    return;
  }
  else {
    // Additional validation failed. Force logout
    module_load_include('pages.inc', 'user');
    user_logout();
  }
}
```

Comments and improvements are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

If You want to abort login I think You should try to add own validate function to user_login whith hook_form_alter (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_login') { // or $form_id = 'user_login_form'
    $form['#validate'][] = 'check_username_against_ad_hoc_service';
  }
}

function check_username_against_ad_hoc_service($form, &$form_state) {
  $name = $form_state['values']['name'];

  if($name == 'NoGo') {
    form_set_error('name', 'You're an Ad-hoc!');
  }
}
?>
```

You can also use function hook_form_FORM_ID_alter (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, many of the logins to the site are coming from SSO, so altering the login form would not be enough. I am editing my original post to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, you could add a `#validate` in `hook_form_user_login_form_alter()` and just set a form error.

However, if you're validating against an external service and perhaps getting user info from that endpoint, the 'most standard' way is probably to use [user_external_login_register()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_external_login_register/7).